# UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/... - Django admin

Tags: python, django, encoding, django-admin

I'm facing an encoding problem in `Django-admin`. I have a model, which represents a language quiz which consists of questions and answers (both are models) inlined to `Quiz` model.

I've created a simple `csv` import. In `Quiz` model, there is a file field. When admin is creating a new `Quiz`, they upload a csv file which calls a signal which parse csv and creates questions and answers for this quiz.

There is no problem with english, but I tried to import French quiz and it raises error.

```
Exception Value:    
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Import signal is very simple:

```
def parse_csv(csv):
    questions = []

for line in csv:

    line = line.strip('\r\n').strip('\n')
    d = {}
    items = line.split(';;')
    def parse_csv(csv):
        questions = []
        i=0
        for line in csv:
            i+=1
            print i
            line = line.strip('\r\n').strip('\n')
            d = {}
            items = line.split(';;')
            question = items[0]
            d['question'] = question
            for item in (x.strip() for x in items[1:]):
                if '|' in item:
                    d['answer'] = item
                else:
                    if 'choices' in d.keys():
                        d['choices'].append(item)
                    else:
                        d['choices'] = [item]
            if 'answer' not in d.keys():
                continue
            questions.append(d)

        return questions


    @receiver(post_save,sender=LanguageQuiz)
    def quiz_import_csv(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
        if created:
            if instance.import_csv:

                questions =  parse_csv(instance.import_csv.readlines())

                for q in questions:
                    question = Question(text=q['question'])
                    question.save()
                    for ch in q['choices']:
                        choice = Choice(text=ch,correct=False)
                        choice.save()
                        question.choices.add(choice)
                    answer = Choice(text=q['answer'].strip('|'),correct=True)
                    answer.save()
                    question.choices.add(answer)
                    question.save()
                    instance.questions.add(question)

            instance.save()
```

Do you know what should I do?

EDIT:

**TRACEBACK:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/language_tests/languagequiz/7/

Django Version: 1.8.12
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'SolutionsForLanguagesApp',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'super_inlines',
 'django_tables2',
 'language_tests',
 'smart_selects',
 'django_extensions',
 'constance',
 'constance.backends.database',
 'nested_inline')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware')


Template error:
In template C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\nested_inline\templates\admin\edit_inline\stacked-nested.html, error at line 9
   ascii

   1 : {% load i18n admin_static %}



   2 : <div class="inline-group{% if recursive_formset %} {{ recursive_formset.formset.prefix|default:"Root" }}-nested-inline {% if prev_prefix %} {{ prev_prefix }}-{{ loopCounter }}-nested-inline{% endif %} nested-inline{% endif %}" id="{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}-group">



   3 : {% with recursive_formset=inline_admin_formset stacked_template='admin/edit_inline/stacked-nested.html' tabular_template='admin/edit_inline/tabular-nested.html'%}



   4 :   <h2>{{ recursive_formset.opts.verbose_name_plural|title }}</h2>



   5 : {{ recursive_formset.formset.management_form }}



   6 : {{ recursive_formset.formset.non_form_errors }}



   7 : 



   8 : {% for inline_admin_form in recursive_formset %}<div class="inline-related{% if forloop.last %} empty-form last-related{% endif %}" id="{{ recursive_formset.formset.prefix }}-{% if not forloop.last %}{{ forloop.counter0 }}{% else %}empty{% endif %}">



   9 :     <h3><b>{{ recursive_formset.opts.verbose_name|title }}:</b>&nbsp;<span class="inline_label">{% if inline_admin_form.original %} {{ inline_admin_form.original }} {% else %}#{{ forloop.counter }}{% endif %}</span>



   10 :     {% if inline_admin_form.show_url %}<a href="../../../r/{{ inline_admin_form.original_content_type_id }}/{{ inline_admin_form.original.id }}/">{% trans "View on site" %}</a>{% endif %}



   11 :         {% if recursive_formset.formset.can_delete and inline_admin_form.original %}<span class="delete">{{ inline_admin_form.deletion_field.field }} {{ inline_admin_form.deletion_field.label_tag }}</span>{% endif %}



   12 :   </h3>



   13 :   {% if inline_admin_form.form.non_field_errors %}{{ inline_admin_form.form.non_field_errors }}{% endif %}



   14 :   {% for fieldset in inline_admin_form %}



   15 :     {% include "admin/includes/fieldset.html" %}



   16 :   {% endfor %}



   17 :   {% if inline_admin_form.pk_field %}{{ inline_admin_form.pk_field.field }}{% endif %}



   18 :   {{ inline_admin_form.fk_field.field }}



   19 :   {% if inline_admin_form.form.nested_formsets %}


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  164.                 response = response.render()
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  158.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  135.         content = template.render(context, self._request)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  210.                     return self._render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  202.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  135.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  202.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  135.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  202.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  217.                             nodelist.append(node.render(context))
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  159.                 return template.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  212.                 return self._render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  202.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  576.             return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  217.                             nodelist.append(node.render(context))
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  329.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  217.                             nodelist.append(node.render(context))
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  329.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  159.                 return template.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  212.                 return self._render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  202.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  576.             return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  217.                             nodelist.append(node.render(context))
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  329.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render
  92.             output = force_text(output)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py" in force_text
  94.                 s = six.text_type(bytes(s), encoding, errors)

Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/language_tests/languagequiz/7/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback, which among other things shows the line that is causing the error. Also, why aren't you using the `csv` module?

Comment: I've attached a traceback, you can find it at the bottom of the question. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I've attached a new traceback. I've changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't tell where you're receiving the error. Please post a line where you receive the error.

This is a very common error when parsing international text. It's solved with one of the following two methods:

#### Encoding with UTF8

```
try:
    print (myThing)
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    print (myThing).encode('UTF8')
```

#### Reading the file as a string

You can also try the following code, [courtesy of David Crook](http://dacrook.com/decoding-woes-solved-python/):

```
dataPath = "somepath.csv" # or other type of file
fil = open(dataPath)
txt = fil.readlines()
txt = ''.join(txt)
works = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), index_col = 0)
doesntWork = pd.read_csv(dataPath, index_col = 0)
```

Comment: Don't know why the downvote but I've attached a traceback at the bottom of the question. Maybe it helps...

Comment: Yes, I tried nothing works. If I try to encode characters before saving them, UnicodeDecodeError is raised during encoding. When I try decode, error is not raised, but when I try to open the quiz in admin, encoding/decoding error raises.

Comment: @Milano want to paste an example string from the quiz that may be causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem too.
When I upload image I see this problem.
I realized that image name must be in English so I changed image name (wich one is in Persian) to some random English name.
for solving this problem create validator for image field to change image name to random English name or just change image name before upload.

Answer (score -3):

The following letters are really common in French: 'é', 'è', 'ç', 'à' and would probably break your code.

> Do you know what should I do?

Write a test for it reproducing the issue. Once you've written it, you can make experiments a lot faster (use inmemory files); add problematic characters in all cells in your test CSV; make sure the problem won't occur again, etc.

And fix it, probably by using `unicode(...)`. For example:

```
text=unicode(q['question'])
```